# How to bootstrap navigation with grid?

Tags: html, css, navigation

Hello stackoverflow community. I was wondering how I implement a menu/navigation with a grid system like this screenshot with bootstrap 4.3?
[image: Navigation]

I tried include the grid into the navigation submenu section.

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                One of three columns
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                One of three columns
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </li>
```

But the code above just give me something like this:
[image: bad]

Thank you! :-)

---- Update ----

My full code, edited but still doesnt work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- bootstrap css includes -->

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #0a1d3d; border-bottom: 4px solid #b70000;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                One of three columns
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                One of three columns
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>


<!-- bootstrap script includes -->
</body>
</html>
```

hope someone can help me =)

Answer (score 0):

replace your container div with this code

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">One of three columns</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">One of three columns</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This doesn't work for me... The result is this: https://i.imgur.com/KWrhwyA.png